# найти номер максимального элемента массива , который меньше 100

Tags: python

найти номер максимального элемента массива , который меньше 100 . Известно, что значения элементов массива положительны и не превосходят 200

прога не работает

```
from random import randint

a=[randint(0,200) for i in range(6)]
m = a[100]
c=0

for i in range(1,6):
  if a[i] > m:
    m = a[i]



print('массив : ',a)
print( m,'максимальный элемент' )
print(i,'номер элемента')
```

Comment: А подумать? Хоть немножко

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Если появляется ошибка, то какая? Если вывод не соответствует желаемому, то какой желаемый и получаемый? Используйте кнопку править

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

a = [randint(0, 200) for i in range(6)]
n = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] < 100 and a[i] > n:
        n = a[i]
  
print('массив : ', a)
print(n, 'максимальный элемент')
print(a.index(n), 'номер элемента')
```

Comment: а как сделать так чтоб он вывод был больше 100

Comment: Максимальный элемент > 100? Заменить a[i] < 100 на a[i] >100

Comment: @Rr Ff Разве этот код решает задачу?

Comment: Действительно. Теперь решает, если элемент меньше 100 существует.

Answer (score 1):

Ну почти всё же получилось, добавьте только условие `который меньше 100`

```
from random import randint

a=[randint(0,200) for i in range(6)]
m = -1
ind = -1

for i in range(len(a)):
    if (a[i] > m) and (a[i] < 100):
         m = a[i]
         ind = i

print('массив : ',a)
if m >= 0:
    print( m,'максимальный элемент' )
    print( 'номер ', ind )
```

Comment: а как его найти

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

a = [randint(0, 200) for i in range(6)]
print(a.index(max(filter(lambda i: i < 100, a))))
```

Comment: Это не решает задачу ;)

Comment: @MBo edited ;)...