# Найти минимальный элемент массива , который больше 150

Tags: python

Найти минимальный элемент массива , который больше 150. Известно что значения элементов массива положительны и не превосходят 300

делаю но вывод неправельный

```
from random import randint

a = [randint(0, 300) for i in range(5)]
n = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i] > 150 and a[i] > n:
    n = a[i]

print('массив : ',a)
print( 'минимальный элемент :',(n) )
print('номер элемента :',i)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178210/398802

Comment: где-то я уже видел похожий вопрос...

Comment: а как сделать так чтоб он показывал минимальный элемент в массиве

Comment: @МагомедШахмаев посмотреть на код и подумать хотя бы 10 секунд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

a = [randint(0, 300) for i in range(5)]
n = 301
min_i = -1
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i] > 150 and a[i] < n:
    n = a[i]
    min_i = i

print('массив : ',a)
print('минимальный элемент :',(n) )
print('номер элемента :', min_i)
```